# parallel ipython/ipcluster through head node

Tags: parallel-processing, ipython

I want to use the parallel capabilities of `ipython` on a remote computer cluster. Only the head node is accessible from the outside. I have set up ssh keys so that I can connect to the head node with e.g. `ssh head` and from there I can also ssh into any node without entering a password, e.g. `ssh node3`. So I can basically run any commands on the nodes by doing:

```
ssh head ssh node3 command
```

Now what I really want to do is to be able to run jobs on the cluster from my own computer from ipython. The way to set up the hosts to use in ipcluster is:

```
send_furl = True
engines = { 'host1.example.com' : 2,
            'host2.example.com' : 5,
            'host3.example.com' : 1,
            'host4.example.com' : 8 }
```

But since I only have a host name for the head node, I don't think I can do this. One option is to set us ssh tunneling on the head node, but I cannot do this in my case, since this requires enough ports to be open to accommodate all the nodes (and this is not the case). Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

I use ipcluster on the NERSC clusters by using the PBS queue:

http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/parallel/parallel_process.html#using-ipcluster-in-pbs-mode

in summary you submit jobs which runs mpiexec ipengine, (after having launched ipcontroller on the login node). Do you have PBS on your cluster?

this was working fine with ipython .10, it is now broken in .11 alpha.

Answer (score 0):

I would set up a [VPN](http://ddg.gg?q=vpn) server on the master, and connect to that with a VPN client on my local machine. Once established, the virtual private network will allow all of the slaves to appear as if they're on the same LAN as my local machine (on a "virtual" network interface, in a "virtual" subnet), and it should be possible to ssh to them.

You could possibly establish that VPN [over SSH](http://bodhizazen.net/Tutorials/VPN-Over-SSH/) ("ssh tunneling", as you mention); other options are [OpenVPN](http://ddg.gg/?q=OpenVPN) and [IPsec](http://ddg.gg/?q=ipsec).

I don't understand what you mean by "this requires enough ports to be open to accommodate all the nodes". You will need: (i) one inbound port on the master, to provide the VPN/tunnel, (ii) inbound SSH on each slave, accessible from the master, (iii) another inbound port on each slave, over which the master drives the IPython engines. Wouldn't (ii) and (iii) be required in any setup? So all we've added is (i).